# Function that return characters from string which occurrences is user definied

Tags: c, string

I really hitted the wall with this type of function. I need to make a function that returns characters from string.

user can enter any number and I need to find char in string where total number of occurrences is number that user specified.

Does someone knows how can it be done in C language?

Comment: Post the code you've written for this so far and then people can help you to get it working.

Comment: Learn about loops. Look up on the `isalpha()` function.

Comment: @Michi let's say user enter number 3 and our test string is "111abcddaaa" it need to find characters in string which total number is three (or more) and it needs to print that character

Comment: @ZhiZha You say number 3, and the giving string is "111abcddaaa", what exactly should be the output ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    unsigned char ac = *(unsigned char *)a;
    unsigned char bc = *(unsigned char *)b;
    return ac < bc ? -1 : ac > bc;
}

char *func(const char *str, size_t n){
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *dup = malloc(len + 1);
    char temp[len + 1];//[256]

    strcpy(dup, str);
    qsort(dup, len, sizeof(*dup), cmp);

    char *p = dup;
    size_t i = 0;
    while(*p){
        char aChar[] = {*p, 0};
        len = strspn(p, aChar);
        if(len == n){
            temp[i++] = *p;
        }
        p += len;
    }
    temp[i] = 0;
    strcpy(dup, temp);
    return dup;
}

int main(void){
    char *occurs = func("111abcddaaa", 1);

    for(char *p = occurs; *p; ++p){
        printf("%c\n", *p);
    }

    free(occurs);

    return 0;
}
```